# How do I update/re-render navigator right button in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How do I update/re-render navigator right button text in react native? basically I used navigator.replace for now but is there a better way? Like "Follow" to "Unfollow"

Comment: right button is for the next scene. typically, navigator.push.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use navigator's props
    var NavigationBarRouteMapper ={
      RightButton: function(route,navigator,index,nevState){
     return(
         <Text }> {navigator.props.rightButtonText} </Text>
        );
      }
    .
    .

    };
```

and in navigator component add the prop and assign a value using state.

```
 <Navigator initialRoute =  {{name:'home'}}
                 renderScene  =  {this.renderScene.bind(this)} 
                 navigationBar = {<Navigator.NavigationBar routeMapper={NavigationBarRouteMapper}/>}
                 rightButtonText ={this.state.RightButtonText}
                />
```

Now if you this.setState({RightButtonText:'Follow'}) somewhere in your main component, its value will be effected.

Comment: how do i update this.state.RightButtonText if i already push to home?

Comment: @phongyewtong you don't have to call push or pop in order to render component. setState method will trigger render and renderScene as well. Ofc you need to set state of component which includes Navigator component.I checked this code.